# Keydown Event Suffix

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

What event is "`keydown.od47`" in the following snippet of JavaScript?

```
$(document).on("keydown.od47", function(a) {
    switch (a.which) {
        case 40:
            foo();
            a.preventDefault();
            break;
        case 32:
            bar();
            a.preventDefault();
            break;
        case 38:
            car(), a.preventDefault()
    }

// ...
});
```

I'm reverse engineering a site's HTML/JS/CSS code that's been minimized/obfuscated. The code snippet has been "pretty printed/prettified" by Google's Chrome browser; result is what you see here.

See snippet below (wasn't kidding):

[image]

Comment: It's probably jQuery and thus a *namespaced event*: https://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names